# D3js sunburst take up entire size of containing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I'm currently working on creating a sunburst using D3.js similar to the one at the link [here](https://bl.ocks.org/maybelinot/5552606564ef37b5de7e47ed2b7dc099). However I like my sunburst to be a bit different. Instead of showing all the arcs, I would like to filter out and only show those arcs that are at one level above the current root node. I have a working version of this through a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsolis/7tactp4z/4/. I have also attached my javascript code below.

```
var data = {
    "name": "root1", 
    "children": [
    {
        "name": "parent1",
        "children": [
        {
            "name": "child1",
            "children": [
            {
                "name": "leaf1",
                "size": 100
            }, 
            {
                "name": "leaf2", 
                "size": 200
            }]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "child2",
            "children": [
            {
                "name": "leaf1",
                "size": 300
            },
            {
                "name": "leaf2",
                "size": 400
            }]
        }]
    },
    {    
        "name": "parent2", 
        "children": [
        {
            "name": "child1", 
            "children": [
            {
                "name": "leaf1", 
                "size": 100
            }, 
            {
                "name": "leaf2", 
                "size": 200
            }]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "child2",
            "children": [
            {
                "name": "leaf1",
                "size": 300
            },
            {
                "name": "leaf2",
                "size": 400
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "parent3", 
        "children": [
        {
            "name": "child1", 
            "children": [
            {
                "name": "leaf1", 
                "size": 100
            }, 
            {
                "name": "leaf2", 
                "size": 200
            }]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "child2",
            "children": [
            {
                "name": "leaf1",
                "size": 300
            },
            {
                "name": "leaf2",
                "size": 400
            }]
        }]
    }]
};

/*
    width and height of svg canvas, aspect ratio, and radius of sunburst
*/

var width     = 500,
    height    = 500,
    radius    = ( Math.min( width, height ) / 2 ) - 10;

/*
    show commas for numbers greater then 999 and use decimal notation

    https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#format
*/
var formatNumber = d3.format(",d");

/*
    range of linear scale x: 0 to 2 * Math.PI 

    https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#linear-scales
*/
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range( [ 0, ( 2 * Math.PI ) ] );

/*
    range of square root scale y: radius

    https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleSqrt
*/
var y = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .range( [ 0, radius ] );

/*
    create an ordinal scale of colors
    where each name is correlated to a color

    https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleOrdinal
    https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#schemeCategory20    
*/
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal( d3.schemeCategory20 );

/*
    creates a default adjancency diagram which is a space-filling
    variant of a node-link tree diagram. Rather than drawing a link between
    parent and child in the hierarchy, nodes are drawn as solid areas (either arcs
    or rectangles) with placements relative to other nodes 

    https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#partition
*/
var partition = d3.partition();

/*
    creates an arc generator that is used to define how big of a slice a particular
    element should take up on the sunburst

    https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#arcs
*/
var arc = d3.arc()
    .startAngle(  function( d ) 
    { 
        return Math.max( 0, Math.min( 2 * Math.PI, x( d.x0 ) ) ); 

    })
    .endAngle(    function( d ) 
    { 
        return Math.max( 0, Math.min( 2 * Math.PI, x( d.x1 ) ) ); 

    })
    .innerRadius( function( d ) 
    { 
        return Math.max( 0, y( d.y0 ) ); 

    })
    .outerRadius( function( d ) 
    { 
        return Math.max( 0, y( d.y1 ) ); 

    });

/*
    creating svg html element with 'width' and 'height' and translating
    it to be the middle of the 'g' tag containing the svg
*/
var svg = d3.select("#sunburst_chart")
        .attr("width",  width  )
        .attr("height", height )
        .append( "g" )
        .attr( "transform", "translate(" + ( width / 2 ) + "," + ( height / 2 ) + ")" );

/*    
    creates a hierarchy root object for d3 where the object
    represents the root of all the data and contains properties
    that can be used to access the associated 'children' data, 
    depth of a node, height, height of a node, etc.

    https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#hierarchy
*/    
var hierarchy_data = d3.hierarchy( data );

/*    
    specifies what each datum should use when a specified datum calls it's 'value'
    function. The node.value property of each node is set to the numeric value 
    returned by the specified function plus the combined value of all descendants.

    https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy
    https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#node_eachAfter
*/    
hierarchy_data.sum( function( d ) 
{ 

    return d.size; 

});

svg.selectAll( "path" )
    /*  
        Specify the data to use for the svg element, .descendants returns an array
        of descendant nodes starting with the root node. 

        https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#node_descendants

    */
    .data( partition( hierarchy_data ).descendants( ) )
    .enter()
    .filter( function ( d )
    {
        return d.depth <= 1;
    })
    .append( "path" )
        /*
            Use the 'arc' generator to generate slices for each datum given a certain value. 

            https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy
        */
        .attr( "d", arc )

        /*
            Fill the slice with a color based off the color ordinal scale.

            https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#arcs
        */
        .style( "fill", function( d ) 
        { 

            return color( ( d.children ? d : d.parent ).data.name ); 

        })
        .append( "title" )

            .text(function( d ) 
            { 

                return d.data.name + "\n" + formatNumber( d.value ); 

            });

svg.select("path").attr("id", "centroid");
```

Without any interaction this is just about what I want, however there is an issue with the sizing. If you inspect the svg element for the sunburst you will notice that the sunburst outer radius is not equal to the width or the height, but is a bit smaller than the actually svg element it is contained inside of. I think this is because my arc is doing my calculations as if there are slices there, however these are filtered out later on by the `d3.filter` function. I would instead like my sunburst to take up the entire amount of space possible given the fact that data is filtered out. Any help will be greatly appreciated, if I need to provide anything else please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `viewBox` attribute to your `svg` element. If your maximum hierarchy depth is 3, then compute the radius of the outermost arc like this:

```
var maxHierarchy = 3;
var depth = 1;
var maxRadius = y((depth + 1) / (maxHierarchy + 1));

var svg = d3.select("#sunburst_chart")
    .attr("width",  width  )
    .attr("height", height )
    .attr("viewBox", (radius - maxRadius) + "," + (radius - maxRadius) + "," +
          (2*maxRadius + 20) + "," + (2*maxRadius + 20))
    .append( "g" )
    .attr( "transform", "translate(" + ( width / 2 ) + "," + ( height / 2 ) + ")" );

 //...

svg.selectAll( "path" )
    //...
    .filter( function ( d )
    {
        return d.depth <= depth;
    })
    //...
```

(The `+ 20` is your padding.)

Comment: I changed the code to implement what you recommended, but now I am getting a weird error where it looks like the graph isn't being shifted over correctly. You can see through the link here : http://imgur.com/a/7qi7K. I've also updated the jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsolis/7tactp4z/5/.

Comment: Sorry, my example it seems was ambiguous. The `translate` attribute is still needed. In addition, don't forget to use the `depth` in the filter.